# Does Chrome's Device Emulator use the built in browser?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Does the iphone 6 emulator in Chrome's Developer Tools show how it would look in the built iOS browser or if you used Chrome's mobile browser on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no." Google does mention some limitations on their page that [discusses the mobile emulator](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode), but they don't seem to admit to all of the bugs/issues.

Mobile1st covers its limitations briefly in [this article](https://mobile1st.com/can-trust-chromes-built-emulator/) where they mention that the emulator is limited in the following area:

> Rendering Engine – this is the code the browser uses to interpret the
>   HTML/CSS and create what we see in the browser.

That's a pretty big shortcoming.

The mobile emulator is a handy tool and I do use it, but I never rely on it. I always go in and test my designs on an actual device. Almost always there are differences and very often the difference are quite significant.